# GroupBox growing in a inherited form

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, groupbox

I´ve created a base form. In this base form, has a groupbox component. When I use this form by inherit, the groupbox inherited is growing more than form. I need to ajust this all the time when I close and open the design of the forms inheriteds by the form base.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it inside a Panel? Use of the Dock property? SizeModes ? ....

Comment: what does your code look like.. we are not inside your heard nor can we see what you see.. so please post some relevant code so that someone may be able to lend a solution

Comment: I can´t post a image yet. using Dock property I think that resolve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using DOCK property of group box in the pagecontrol I´ve resolved my problem. Thanks all for reply.